# How to link various Google spreadsheets using IMPORTRANGEs that contain VLOOKUP formulas without getting #N/A returned?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-vlookup, importrange

The problem:

When using `IMPORTRANGE` to pull data from a different spreadsheet, cells in the origin spreadsheet that contain a formule containing VLOOKUP often (but not always) return `#N/A (ERROR: Did not find value 'xxx'  in VLOOKUP evaluation)`. In the origin sheet the formulas are calculated correctly and showing a value though. This does not always happen, sometimes it does pull in the proper value.

The intent:

To take data from different spreadsheets, combine them in a different spreadsheet and do some calculations on them. And then pull info from this calculation spreadsheet (or from multiple calculation spreadsheets) into a reporting spreadsheet for some further calculations and formatting.

The set-up:

There are several source data spreadsheets,say `dataspreadsheet1`, `dataspreadsheet2` and `dataspreadsheet3`. A calculation spreadsheet (`calcspreadsheet`) is created that creates a copy of `sheet1` in each of the data spreadsheets and names these sheets `datasheet1`, `datasheet2` and `datasheet3` respectively. The `IMPORTRANGE` statement used for this is created as follows: `importrange(+VLOOKUP("dataspreadsheet1",filelist!A1:C1000,3,FALSE),"sheet1!a1:Z1000")` where
`filelist!A1:C1000` is a sheet in `calcspreadsheet` that contains Name, Type and Id in respective columns.

The values in each of these sheets `datasheet1-3` are then used for calculations in another sheet, `calcsheet1` in the `calcspreadsheet`. As the main goal of this is to add up daily values from the 3 `dataspreadsheets`, but those `sourcesheets` do not all have the same data on the same line a `VLOOKUP` is used again to make sure additions for a date use the line for the date in `datasheet1-3` regardless of its row number. E.g. `VLOOKUP($A11,'datasheet1'!$A:$P,4) + VLOOKUP($A11,'datasheet2'!$A:$P,4) + VLOOKUP($A11,'datasheet3'!$A:$P,4)` where column A is the date column in all sheets.

This appears to work fine, although upon opening `calcspreadsheet` it can take a long time for it to go through an update, during which time lots of `#N/A`'s are displayed. Eventually it comes right though.

The problem arise when a `reportspreadsheet` is created that in turn used an `IMPORTRANGE` call to pull the info from `calcsheet1` in order to be able to work with it. This often, but not always, results in the problem states at the start. The `IMPORTRANGE` call in this `reportspreadsheet` is generated in a similar way as that in the `calcspreadsheet`: `=importrange(+VLOOKUP(calc!B1,sheetcodes!A1:C3000,3,FALSE),"sheet1!a1:Z1000")` where `calc!B1` contains the name of the source spreadsheet (in this `calc` that would be 'calcspreadsheet' and `sheetcodes!A1:C3000` again contains a list of sheets with `Name`, `Type` and `Id` in respective columns

A work-around I tried:

What I did notice that `IMPORTRANGE` works better on cells that do not contain `VLOOKUP` So I tried to copy the content of `calcsheet` to another sheet in `calcspreadsheet`, called `exportsheet` but having only the values in there, not formulas and then use `IMPORTRANGE` on this `exportsheet`.  The copy script used is as follows:

```
function exportPrep() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("stream");
  //sheet.activate();

  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("calcsheet");
  var sourceDataRange = source.getDataRange();
  var sourceSheetValues = sourceDataRange.getValues();
  var sourceRows = sourceDataRange.getNumRows();
  var sourceColumns = sourceDataRange.getNumColumns();

  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(destination.setActiveSheet("exportsheet"));
  destination.getDataRange().offset(0, 0, sourceRows, sourceColumns).setValues(sourceSheetValues);
      }
```

This seemed to work, but unfortunately the copy script used to copy the value of calcsheet into exportsheet now showed the same behaviour, it would sometimes work and sometimes give the `#N/A` and so leaves me with the same problem.

My questions:

I've read various posts with similar issues and responses that mentioned this function was temperamental or had a bug. Other stated it is not possible to use dynamic references in `IMPORTRANGE`. Given that it sometimes works and sometimes not I suspect the function itself might be correct but that there are sync or time-out issues in the set-up.

> How can I set up the above functionality. Either with the use of `IMPORTRANGE` and `VLOOKUP` at all with some changes/additions, or built in a different way from the get-go.

Comment: Are you using old or new style google sheets? ... Also can you confirm that it is vlookup/importrange that is the cause of the #N/A and not custom functions, because every time I have seen this, the cause has been custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

So I've not done this with importrange but I when I have this issue with Vlookup I wrap the vlookup in an IF and test for the #N/A.
Try something like: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(...)),"",VLOOKUP(...))

Answer (score 0):

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B81,'KAM_Q3_OPPS STAGE_(H/I/L/M/N)'!$F$3:$G$111,2,False),)`

This is the best way I found to do it and the last two values `[ , ) ]` make the new output, in this case it is nothing.

IF you wanted 0 put in then you would do `[ ,0) ]`